# Unable to mount windows partitons in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, 17.10

I have recently dual booted win 10 with Ubuntu 17.10 and everything is working fine but I am not able to mount windows drives, i.e., local disk C (sda3 in photo) and local disk E (sda4).
I have already disabled fast startup in windows.
Terminal result is attached with photo 
blkid andlsblk -f results are in photo
Photo links 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1013653/edit) your question and add output of `blkid` and `lsblk -f` to it.

Comment: I have added blkid and lsblk -f results in question. Please help

Comment: As you can see `lsblk` does not show filesystems on sda2, sda3 and sda4. I do not know why. And please post terminal output as text instead of images.